# More than 3 options are not working while declaring Xtext grammar

Tags: antlr, dsl, xtext, xtend

Particularly when I use more than 3 OR symbols.

```
datatype:
    Integer | Float | Char | Blah | Blah
entity:
    Class | Struct | Enumeration | Union
```

the complete grammar can be found here: https://gist.github.com/Mrprofessor/7b8df3f00c75ef2ac67bffd0a20e983c

Comment: What error do you get? Could you share a small reproducible Xtext grammar? Your grammar is not self-contained and looks bogus, e.g. missing semicolons.

Comment: [Check here please..!!](https://gist.github.com/Mrprofessor/7b8df3f00c75ef2ac67bffd0a20e983c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your grammar is ambigous

consider this model

```
Bla;
Blubb;
Pling;
```

are these Bits | Pointers | Labels | Entrys | Logicals | HwordLogicals | Bytes

Comment: Well yeah..I get you..I am just learning now.So before writing rules I just wanted to make sure whether these are working or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys.I was just giving a try to xtext. Got your point by the way.